# IDbConnection and using blocks in c#

Tags: c#, using, using-statement, idbconnection

I understand that wrapping an IDbConnection object in a using block ensures that Dispose will get called and the resources it is using will get freed. That being said do I also need to wrap IDbCommand and IDataReader in using blocks as well, or is just wrapping the connection object sufficient. Thanks.

Comment: It depends on the actual application you are designing.  In my work, I need a persistent connection so I don't wrap the connection object in using statements, instead I wrap all the command and readers inside using statements and try/catch blocks, making sure that the finally of every try/catch closes the connection.  That way the connection is persistent...but stays closed when not in use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of easy ways to work out the answer to this for any given object without consulting the documentation:

1. If you wrap it in a `using` block and it's not `IDisposable`, you'll get a syntax error.
2. If your class has a `.Dispose` method (easily checked in Intellisense) then you should wrap it.
3. If your class implements `IDisposable` (easily checked through "go to definition" or the new "peek" functionality in VS) you should wrap it.

Alternatively, by way of example, you can see from the [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idbcommand%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that `IDbCommand` implements `IDisposable` and therefore *should* be disposed of with a `using` block.

Comment: Ad 2) `using` matching is based on interface, so method may be there, but if it doesn't implement `IDisposable` you wan't be able to use it in `using` statement. And  `IDisposable.Dispose` can be implemented explicitely and method may not be seen in Intellisense.

Comment: True (often the method will be `.Close()` or similar), but it's still a reasonable way of checking. Ultimately I'd always check for the interface (#3), but the other methods are occasionally useful.

Answer (score 1):

The best practice is to wrap any scoped IDisposable object in a using block.  This is especially true when you are writing code to interact with interfaces, since you have no idea of the details of the underlying implementations; it might matter in some cases.